# Cannot checkout subversion repository via WebStorm

Tags: macos, svn, ssl, webstorm, self-signed

I am working with a Subversion-Repository hosted by a server with self-signed certificate.

I can look at the repository through the browser (tested with Safari, Chrome, Firefox), I can checkout the repository through the command-line tool, but when trying to checkout through WebStorm I get the error message:

> Subversion: (Accessing URL: https://svn/dat/mad) Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Please check Subversion SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1

I already tried SSLv3 (should be the correct protocol), TLSv1 and accept all (and I cleared the auth cache every time)